# How do I solve this by linear differential equation $x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=x\ln x$?

Tags: calculus

How do I solve the following by linear differentiation: $$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=\ln x$$  I'm not seeing how to deal with the $\ln x$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just eye-balling it, I get $y=-1-\ln x.$

Comment: What is “linear differentiation?” From your comment on the answer below, it is a technique, but the only thing I can find is “linear differential equations,” which is just a type of problem.

Comment: Call @ThomasAndrews's solution $y_0$. Then, you have $x(y-y_0)'-(y-y_0)=0$, which is separable.

Comment: Should $xy^\prime-y$ be $x\ln x$ or $\ln x$?

Comment: Your title and question say $2$ different things; one says $\ln x$ and the other says $x\ln x$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the integrating factor method?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint. Make the terms on the left have some symmetry:

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y\frac{dx}{dx}=\ln(x)$$

Then given that shape on the left, it suggest the quotient rule:

$$\frac{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y\frac{dx}{dx}}{x^2}=\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I have to solve by linear differentiation

Comment: Add the word “by” to your question, then. I also didn’t read it to mean you needed a particular technique. @GlennNyirenda

Comment: @GlennNyirenda The equation you presented is a "linear differential equation". It can be solved using many techniques. I don't think there is a technique commonly known as "linear differentiation". Is it possible you have mixed up the nomenclature for this type of equation with some technique? In the term "linear differentiation", "linear" is an adjective for "differentiation", which is redundant since differentiation is a linear action. So something seems off with the vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for the solution to a first order linear ODE is, given

$$y'+Py=Q,$$
$$y=e^{-\int P}\left(C+\int Qe^{\int P}\right).$$
If you memorize this, you'll never have first order linear ODE troubles again. Putting $$P=-\dfrac{1}{x}, \ Q =\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$$ we obtain
$$y = x\left(C+\int \dfrac{\ln x}{x^2}dx\right)=x\left(C-\dfrac{\ln x+1}{x}\right).$$